# Apply function over a list only if list members satisfy multiple conditions

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional

I want to apply a function to members of a list only if all the members of the list satisfy a set of conditions otherwise return a result of zero. For example for

```
list1 = {0, "", " ", 1, 5, 6};
list2 = {1, 4, 3, 6, 7, 9, 9, 11};
```

the desired output would be

```
f[list1]
f[list2] (* e.g. Plus@@list *)
```

> 0
>
> 50

What I've tried so far:

```
f[list_] := 
 If[(# == 0 || N[#] == "" || N[#] == " "), 0, 
    Plus @@ list] & /@ list
f[list1]
f[list2]
```

> {0, 0, 0, 12 + "" + " ", 12 + "" + " ", 12 + "" + " "}
>   {50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50}

It's clear to me why this didn't work but I can't quite see the appropriate chicanery. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f]
f[list_] := If[FreeQ[list, 0 | "" | " "], Plus @@ list, 0]

f[list1]
```

> 0

```
f[list2]
```

> 50

Alternatively,

```
ClearAll[f2]
f2[list_] := Boole[FreeQ[list, 0 | "" | " "]] Plus @@ list;

f2[list1]
```

> 0

```
f2[list2]
```

> 50

Or

```
ClearAll[f3]
f3[lst : {Except[Alternatives[0, "", " "]] ..}] := Plus @@ lst
f3[{__}] := 0

f3[list1]
```

> 0

```
f3[list2]
```

> 50

Answer (score 2):

Another way to build the function is:

```
g[x_] := If[Length@Select[x, NumberQ] == Length[x], Total[x], 0];
{g[list1], g[list2]}
{0, 50}
```